# Extract AUDIO, manipulate & merge again

Tags: linux, bash, shell, audio, ffmpeg

I'm using [Spleeter](https://github.com/deezer/spleeter) to remove music from audios.

My goal is to build a script that automates the process of extracting audio from the video, execute Spleeter on the extracted audio & than merge the manipulated audio back to the video replacing the original one.

The main issue I had is that I don't have enough ram to process the whole extracted audio. I need to split it the into multiple pieces & execute Spleeter upon each piece.

Then concatenate the manipulated pieces together and merge the result to the video.

Here's what I tried:

```
#!/bin/bash

cd ~/Desktop/Video-convert

# create audio from video
ffmpeg -i *.mp4 output.mp3

# Split the audio into pieces
ffmpeg -i output.mp3 -f segment -segment_time 120 -c copy output_%03d.mp3


# Execute Spleeter upon each sample
FILES=~/Desktop/Video-convert/*.mp3

for f in $FILES
do
  spleeter separate -i $f -o output_vocal
done

# delete unneeded audios
rm *.mp3
cd output_vocal

# ===========================================================
# the problem starts here
# ===========================================================

# concatenate manipulated audios together
find . -name 'vocals.wav' -exec echo {} >> mylist.txt \;

ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i mylist.txt -c copy vocal.mp3

mv vocal.mp3 ../

cd ../

# merge the audio back to video
ffmpeg -i *.mp4 -i vocal.mp3 \
-c:v copy -c:a aac -strict experimental \
-map 0:v:0 -map 1:a:0 vocal-vid.mp4
```

Everything works well until having to concatenate the audios together. Spleeter outputs the result into **vocal.wav** & **accompaniment.wav** within a sub-folder that is named the same as the audio that was processed.

The File Tree looks like this:

```
output_vocal
- output_000
----- vocal.wav
----- accompaniment.wav
- output_001
----- vocal.wav
----- accompaniment.wav
- output_002
----- vocal.wav
----- accompaniment.wav
```

As you can see the problem comes with the naming. My objective is to concatenate all **vocal.wav** into one mp3 audio.

And then merge the final **vocal.mp3** audio with the ***.mp4** video.

Only issue is going around the way that Spleeter outputs the result audios.

Comment: so what is the problem? is it just the typo "vocals.wav" vs "vocal.wav"?

Comment: Even with the typo fixed it wouldn't work. The audios aren't being concatenated together. The mylist.txt is empty.

Comment: Something is wrong with: 

[ find . -name 'vocals.wav' -exec echo {} >> mylist.txt \; ]

My error is that the final vocal.mp3 doesn't exist 
Can't figure out how to concatenate the audios together into a vocal.mp3.

Comment: the `find` command doesn't do any concatenation, but it creates a list of files (and puts it into another file "mylist.txt"). if the content of "mylist.txt" is what you expect, then this cmd does work. else we need to know what it does contain after you run it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem you are experiencing is that ffmpeg's `concat` demuxer requires an input file that contains directives, rather than a naive file-list.

Your `find` invocation creates a file like:

```
output_vocal/output_000/vocal.wav
output_vocal/output_001/vocal.wav
output_vocal/output_002/vocal.wav
```

whereas ffmpeg's `concat` demuxer really requires a file like:

```
file output_vocal/output_000/vocal.wav
file output_vocal/output_001/vocal.wav
file output_vocal/output_002/vocal.wav
```

Also note that `find` does not necessarily return the files in alphabetic order, whereas you will most likely want to concatenate the files in that order.

Finally, when concatenating the WAV-files, you cannot use the `copy` codec to generate an MP3 file (since the WAV/RIFF codec is not MP3). but you don't need an intermediate MP3-file anyhow

Here's an updated script, that
- uses a temporary directory for all intermediate files
- iterates over all mp4-files provided at the cmdline (rather than hardcoding the input directory)
- creates a "XXX_voc.mp4" file for each input file "XXX.mp4" (overwriting any existing files)

```sh
#!/bin/bash

for infile in "$@"
do
  outfile=${infile%.mp4}_voc.mp4

  # create a temp-directory to put our stuff to
  TMPDIR=$(mktemp -d)

  # create audio from video
  ffmpeg -i "${infile}" "${TMPDIR}/output.mp3"

  # Split the audio into pieces
  ffmpeg -i "${TMPDIR}/output.mp3" -f segment -segment_time 120 -c copy "${TMPDIR}/output_%03d.mp3"

  # Execute Spleeter upon each sample
  find "${TMPDIR}" -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "output_*.mp3" \
    -exec spleeter separate -i {} -o "${TMPDIR}/output_vocal" ";"

  # find all 'vocal.wav' files generated by spleeter, sort them, 
  # prefix them with 'file ', and put them into output.txt
  find "${TMPDIR}/output_vocal" -type f -name "vocal.wav" -print0 \
  | sort -z \
  | xargs -0 -I{} echo "file '{}'" \
  > "${TMPDIR}/output.txt"
  # concatenate the files and create an MP3 file
  ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i "${TMPDIR}/output.txt" -c copy "${TMPDIR}/vocal.wav"

  # merge the audio back to video
  ffmpeg -y -i "${infile}" -i "${TMPDIR}/vocal.wav" \
    -c:v copy -c:a aac -strict experimental \
    -map 0:v:0 -map 1:a:0 "${outfile}"

  rm -rf "${TMPDIR}"
done
```